# Android log event

Tags: android, notifications, logcat

Is there any nice to way to get notifications/intents/changes from the systemlog in Android.

Logcat only shows the latest part of the systemlog which I find very limited and I would like to stream the changes to a webserver or such from an application.

/Br Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that your app requires android.permission.READ_LOGS, you can run logcat on the device itself, and [read its output with Process.getInputStream()](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/SendLogActivity.java?spec=svn13&r=12#235).

I haven't tested it, but I think it should allow to retrieve live logcat output (provided that you omit the -d option in the example above).

Apart from running logcat on the device, I don't think there's any way to access the log or get notified about new messages.